# Grails internals : Auto mapping and Domain object creation

Tags: grails

I am trying to make a taglib to represent an object (to read and display at the UI). When creating an object (save method in the controller), I see the domain class and association are created by the auto assignment of parameter

```
def Book = new Book(params)
```

It also maps complex types (for eg: joda time). I wonder about the naming convention necessary to facilitate this mapping. Out of curiosity, can someone also point where in the grails source code I could see how grails handles this mapping. I'm still learning Spring and probably this would be a good exercise.
Thanks, 
Babu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK the naming conventions are rather straightforward. If there's a field `params.foo` and the object you are binding to has a field foo, it will bind the value, assuming the type conversion works properly. If there's a `params.bar.id` set with an Long value and your object has a complex property of type `Bar`, it will lookup this instance and inject it.

If you need more control over the binding process, you might want to use [bindData](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/bindData.html).

If you are interested into the details of the binding process, have a look at Java's [PropertyEditor](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyEditor.html) as this is what is being used in the background. I wrote a [blog post](http://www.jakusys.de/blog/2008/08/grails-custom-datatypes-conversion/) on how to create and register PropertyEditors a while ago, maybe it helps you getting started with that stuff.

Comment: thanks a lot.. i read few of your articles (especially like the tutorial on scaffolding template).. thanks again for ur reply.. i'll go through the details...